# SSIS ODBC Connection Password

Tags: ssis, odbc

So, I have an ODBC connection with connectionstring:

```
Driver={HDBODBC32};uid=########;servernode=#########.######.####.com:12345
```

This runs fine on my local machine with ProtectionLevel = 'Encrypt...'

However because my package will ultimately be run by a scheduling agent, I changed the level to 'Dont save sensitive data', and used expressions to set the password from variable.

Result : 
Error: There was an error trying to establish an Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) connection with the database server

I have used the password/variable approach successfully before on OLE DB connections to SQL server, so the problem now is either because this is ODBC not OLEDB, or because of the HANA driver - I have no idea which why or how !!

Any clues appreciated !

Comment: Which version of SSIS are you using? 2012+?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Does the server you are deploying it to have access (firewall and/or ID) to the server you are trying to connect to?